# Maven ant task wildcard exclusion does not work

Tags: maven, ant, maven-ant-tasks

I just started using maven ant task, and one issue I found today was, when the pom contains wildward exclusion, seems the artifacts won’t be excluded.

My script snippet below:

Ant:

```
<artifact:dependencies filesetId="ls.jar.all">
    <pom file="ls-jar-all.pom.xml" />
</artifact:dependencies>
```

Ls-jar-all.pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-bundle</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.apache.abdera</groupId>
            <artifactId>*</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
            <artifactId>*</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

While changing wildcard to individual artifactIds, the exclusion works. (the wildward pom works when using maven)

Any suggestions, thanks